# Pegar o conteúdo file input CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Estou tendo problemas ao pegar o conteúdo de um input de arquivo usando o CKEditor.

Já testei usando o `getlementById` e tudo mais, mas como o pop-up de envio de arquivo é criado após o DOM da página não funciona.

Também testei dessa forma sem sucesso:

```
var element = CKEDITOR.document.getById( 'cke_145_fileInput_input' );
```

Comment: Chegou a dar uma consultada na documentação? Eles indicam usar: `var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData();` complementando http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData

Comment: Já testei. Eu uso ASP VBS e quero fazer um upload sem componentes. Quando o usuário selecionasse o arquivo eu gostaria de converter para base64, jogar esse dado num campo e quando enviasse pro servidor eu usaria um método para salvar essa imagem base64, mas não estou conseguindo fazer essa função. Já tenho o upload funcionando com o componente ASPUpload, mas fica muito lento e expira a página.